# Double integral vs integrating 2-form

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

Is integrating a 2-form with single integral same as integrating the equivalent 1-form with double integral? i.e. is the following true?

$$\iint_{S} dxdy = \int_S dx \wedge dy$$
where S is a 2d manifold.

Comment: There is no 1-form in that equation. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the dx and dy are 1-form?

Comment: yes but what are you interpreting the $dxdy$ as? Usually the notation in the left hand side is the usual Riemann integral, but since you are in a general 2-manifold that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Only when you've pulled back the $2$-form by the parametrization of $S$ to a subset of $\Bbb R^2$ can you do a usual double integral.